# Vertical align baseline and margins

Tags: css, vertical-alignment

So I have some HTML/CSS that looks like this: http://jsfiddle.net/nw2Ym/1/

CSS:

```
.heading {
    font-size: 24px;
}

.badge {
    font-size: 10px;
    padding: 3px 10px;
    background: gray;
    color: #fff;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    margin-bottom: 3px;
    display: inline-block;

}
```

HTML:

```
<div>
    <span class="heading">Testing Stuff</span>
    <span class="badge">OMG!</span>
</div>

Other Text, Other Text, Other Text, Other Text, Other Text, Other Text, Other Text, Other Text, Other Text, Other Text, Other Text, Other Text, Other Text, Other Text, Other Text, Other Text, Other Text, Other Text, Other Text, Other Text, Other Text, Other Text, Other Text, Other Text, Other Text, Other Text, Other Text, Other Text, Other Text, Other Text, Other Text, Other Text, Other Text, Other Text, Other Text, Other Text, Other Text, Other Text, Other Text, Other Text, Other Text, Other Text, Other Text, Other Text,
```

What I want is to align the bottom of the badge with the bottom of the text it is next to. What instead happens the that the bottom of the text aligns with the bottom of the text in the badge.

At that point I thought I'd push the badge up by the size of its padding so I added a margin. Instead of pushing the label up, it ends up pushing stuff under it down. Why does this happen? Also, how can I align the badge so that the bottom (after padding) aligns with the text?

Comment: What do you mean by badge?

Comment: @j08691 I updated the question. I changed label to badge in the html/css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for

```
vertical-align: text-bottom;
```

[Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jcurran/D24Ty/)

Comment: Yes!! I felt like I tried every combo, but must have missed this one. Thanks!